# Capturing string parts in RegEx

Tags: regex, calibre

I would like to map different parts of a string, some of them are optionally presented, some of them are always there. I'm using the Calibre's built in function (based on Python regex), but it is a general question: how can I do it in regex?

Sample strings:

```
!!Mixed Fortunes - An Economic History of China Russia and the West 0198703635 by Vladimir Popov (Jun 17, 2014 4_1).pdf
!Mixed Fortunes - An Economic History of China Russia and the West 0198703635 by Vladimir Popov (Jun 17, 2014 4_1).pdf
Mixed Fortunes - An Economic History of China Russia and the West 0198703635 by Vladimir Popov (Jun 17, 2014 4_1).pdf
!!Mixed Fortunes - An Economic History of China Russia and the West by Vladimir Popov (Jun 17, 2014 4_1).pdf
!!Mixed Fortunes - An Economic History of China Russia and the West by 1 Vladimir Popov (Jun 17, 2014 4_1).pdf
```

The strings' structure is the following:

```
[importance markings if any, it can be '!' or '!!'][title][ISBN-10 if available]by[author]([publication date and other metadata]).[file type]
```

Finally I created this regular expression, but it is not perfect, because if ISBN presented the title will contain the ISBN part too...

```
(?P<title>[A-Za-z0-9].+(?P<isbn>[0-9]{10})|([A-Za-z0-9].*))\sby\s.*?(?P<author>[A-Z0-9].*)(?=\s\()
```

Here is my sandbox: https://regex101.com/r/K2FzpH/1

I really appreciate any help!

Comment: It is not quite sure what exactly you are trying to achieve, but it is clear that you cannot separately match an ISBN when inside the title. I [suggest using](https://regex101.com/r/RbOZ1J/1) something like `^!*(.*?) - (.*?)\s+by\s+([^()]*?)\s*\(([^()]*)\)\.\w+$` first, and then use a more specific pattern for the ISBNs.

Comment: If you don't want to match the last 2 strings `^!*(?P<title>[A-Za-z0-9].+?)\s+(?P<isbn>[0-9]{10})\s+by\s+(?P<author>[A-Z0-9][^(]+)(?=\s\()`  https://regex101.com/r/Xru22s/1

Comment: Or optionally match the isbn number `^!*(?P<title>[A-Za-z0-9].+?)(?:\s+(?P<isbn>[0-9]{10}))?\s+by\s+(?P<author>[A-Z0-9][^(]+)(?=\s\()` https://regex101.com/r/5XLXWA/1

Comment: Thanks, this one seems to be perfect: ```^!*(?P<title>[A-Za-z0-9].+?)(?:\s+(?P<isbn>[0-9]{10}))?\s+by\s+(?P<author>[A-Z0-9][^(]+)(?=\s\()```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using an alteration, you could use:

```
^!*(?P<title>[A-Za-z0-9].+?)(?:\s+(?P<isbn>[0-9]{10}))?\s+by\s+(?P<author>[A-Z0-9][^(]+)(?=\s\()
```

- `^` Start of the string
- `!*` Match optional exclamation marks
- `(?P<title>[A-Za-z0-9].+?)` Named group `title`, match of the ranges in the character class followed by matching as least as possible chars
- `(?:\s+(?P<isbn>[0-9]{10}))?` Optionally match 1+ whitespace chars and named group `isbn` which matches 10 digits
- `\s+by\s+` Match `by` between 1 or more whitspace chars
- `(?P<author>[A-Z0-9][^(]+)` Named group `author` Match either A-Z or 0-9 followed by 1+ times any char except `(`
- `(?=\s\()` Positive lookahead to assert `(` directly to the right

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5XLXWA/1)